# Office Addin load latest version programmatically

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, clickonce, office-addins

I am developing an Office addin, there is a requirement from client that latest version of addin should load on user's system. It will be deployed as Admin Managed addin, but when we upload a new version it is not auto updated. User has to go to Office Add-in screen and press refresh button. Is there some way that I can perform these steps programmatically.

Also if I cannot do the above auto refresh, can I clear Office cache through javascript on my taskpane so that next time it loads latest version? I know that I can [clear chache manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache), but I want to achieve it programmatically.

If I cannot achieve both of the above tasks, can we deploy Office-js addin as click-once app as we can do with VSTO apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we deploy Office-js addin as click-once app as we can do with VSTO apps?

No, Office web add-ins (OfficeJS) can't use ClickOnce for deployments. You can read about possible ways of deployments in the [Deploy and publish Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish) article.

> can I clear Office cache through javascript on my taskpane so that next time it loads latest version?

Nope. Instead, you can set up http-properties on the files. Use `Cache-control` HTTP directives to control who can cache the response, under which conditions, and for how long. See [Guide for Caching and HTTP Cache Headers for Static Content](https://imagekit.io/blog/ultimate-guide-to-http-caching-for-static-assets/) for more information.

So, you may instruct the end point (web browser) for how long to keep old files and when to refresh them. Going that way you may force the browser to update the add-in files.

Comment: in our case, we want to use cache as loading contents again from server gives a feeling that addin is slow. To avoid it, we have renamed all files and updated links to point to new files after every build. Only issue is that Office is not loading latest Manifest file. Even though Microsoft documentation says that It will be updated automatically, but all users are reporting that they have to update manually.

Comment: Correct. The manifest file should be updated manually (sideloaded) or submitted to the app store from where it can be deployed to clients.